# Find the probability of one random variable using another one

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A biased spinner can only land on $1,2,3 or 4 $ .The random variable $X$ represents the number that the spinner lands on after a single spin and $P(X=r) = P(x=r+2)$ for
$r=1,2$

Given that $P(X=2)= 0.35$

a) Find a complete probability distribution of $X$

Ambroh spins the spinner 60 times .

b) find the probability that more that half of the spins land on the number 4

The random variable $Y= \frac{X}{12}$

c) Find $P(Y-X \leq4) $

My attempt .

$P(X=1) = P(X=3) = x $ , $P(X=2) = P(X=4) = 0.35$

$2x = 1-0.65= 0.35 $ , $x=0.175$

b) let $T$ is the random variable that represents the number of times the spinner lands on 4 ,
Then $T$ follows a binomial distribution $B(60 , 0.35)$
We need to find $P(X\geq 31)= 1-P(X\leq 30) = 0.006 $

For number C i do not know how can i get the required probability using the random variable $X$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For $c)$ you can simply plug in $Y$, i.e.

\begin{align}
P(Y - X \leq 4) = P(\tfrac{X}{12} - X \leq 4) = P(X(\tfrac{1}{12} - 1) \leq 4) = P(\tfrac{-11}{12}X \leq 4) = P(X \geq \tfrac{-48}{11})
\end{align}

This is clearly equal to $1$. Hope this helps!